# How can I check the value of nested items of array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 80
            [seen] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
            [seen] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
            [seen] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
            [seen] => 0
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
            [seen] => 0
        )
)
```

I need to check whether is there any `[seen] = 1` or not?

```
if ( /* ??? */ ){
    echo "Yes, at least one of [seen] keys is 1";
} else {
    echo "No, all [seen] keys are 0";
}
```

How can I create that condition ?

Comment: If you're only needing to look for `seen = 1` once, then a normal `foreach` loop would work, just add an if condition checking if `seen == 1` and if so `break;`

Comment: Take a look at `array_column()` and `in_array()`

Comment: as usual, array incantation function one liner: `array_sum(array_column('seen', $array)) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `foreach` loop can help you

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
 if ($arr['seen']==1){
   echo 'SEEN';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$seen = false; 
foreach($my_array as $el){
    if($el['seen']){
        $seen = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

`$seen` is true if at least one of [seen] keys is 1

`$seen` is false if all [seen] keys are 0

Answer (score 0):

Taking a functional approach, you can filter the array using a function that tests for `'seen' == 1`. Then if the resulting array is non-empty, you know there are some elements that have `'seen' == 1` values.

```
<?php

$ar = array(
    0 => array(
        'score' => 80,
        'seen' => 1 ),
    1 => array(
        'score' => 4,
        'seen' => 1 ),
    2 => array(
        'score' => 4,
        'seen' => 0 )
        );

if ( array_filter($ar, function($x) { return $x['seen'] == 1; }) ){
    echo "Yes, at least one of [seen] keys is 1";
} else {
    echo "No, all [seen] keys are 0";
}  

?>
```

Of course, this method is less efficient than those which break out of a loop as soon as a single `'seen' == 1` element is found. But it does give you a single expression in your conditional.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$seen = in_array(1, array_column($array, 'seen'));
```

Documentation:

- [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)